# HTTPS Server Can't Find SocketIO but Http can

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https, socket.io

I'm just learning how to use https for my nodejs web app, and I'm trying to use Socket.IO. However when I try to include the socket.io js for my client side I get an error.

[image]

My Client Side Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hi</h1>
<button onclick="newMSG()">Test</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Client JS:

```
const sock = io();

function newMSG(){
sock.emit('newPost', 'test','123','4:40am')
}
```

My server side:

```
const socketio = require("socket.io");
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const clientPath = `${__dirname}/../client/`;
app.use(express.static(clientPath));

const credentials = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('KEY'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('CERT')
};

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(80);
httpsServer.listen(443);

const io = socketio(httpServer);

io.on('connection', (sock) => {
    sock.emit('messageI', 'Server: User Connected');
    console.log("New Connection");

    sock.on('newPost', (title,text, account, time) => {
        var info = {
            titleP: title,
            textP: text,
            accountP: account,
            timeP:time
        }
        savedData = JSON.stringify(info)
        fileName = title.substring(0,5) + ".json"
        fs.writeFile(filename, savedData)
    });
});


httpServer.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('server error:', err);
});
```

Notably this issue only occurs when I visit the HTTPS version of my site, and not my HTTP version. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I resolved the "middle" error in my screenshot by adding a second "/" before the script

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it. I just needed to move the socket.io from my http server to the https on the server side